# Receiving "403 You don't have permission to access / on this server" in a Codeigniter app

Tags: codeigniter

I have make a site in CodeIgniter it was working fine but suddenly some thing happens and when I login with the site it says "You don't have permission to access / on this server."  Even if I hit the landing page it stops working. The site is live and hosted by CWP.

Comment: Check if your vhost folder corresponds to where your files are on the server, make sure your files are still in the folder you expect them to be in, check the permissions on the vhost folder and everything above that location. This is an Apache issue, and is not particular to CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sholud change the permission of the directory to 755 which you want to access on browser ...

sudo chmod 755 /path_to_directory

or for directory and sub directories

sudo chmod -R 755 /path_to_directory

Comment: Site works well but when i login with the site the 403 error issue occurs , can you please specify the directory from where i have to run the command